# Rename Pyspark output file in azure blob storage using Python or Pyspark code

Tags: python, azure, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark.
We have 'part-0000...' files in azure blob storage. I need to rename those files.
I have searched on the internet but none found better as many answers were in Scala but I want in PySpark or Python.
Tried this

```
fs.rename(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path+"part*"), spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path+"target.csv"))
```

Didn't find any proper answer here as well. Can anyone through some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

able to answer this using dbutils but not sure if it is correct way or not

```
old_file_name = "test1.csv"
new_file_name = "test2.csv"

dbutils.fs.mv(old_file_name,new_file_name)
```

it is working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).